# how to close a Figure when using tk backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

So I am saving a lot of plots.

Olde code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


for args in lots_of_things_to_make:
    fig = plt.figure()
    do_the_fancy_graphing(fig, *args)
    fig.savefig(out_path)
    plt.close()
```

other parts of my code are using Tkinter so I can not use pyplot.

New code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


for args in lots_of_things_to_make:
    fig = Figure()
    do_the_fancy_graphing(fig, *args)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    fig.savefig(out_path)
```

this leads to `_tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer`

How can I close a Figure when using tk backend?

Comment: @eric AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: Don't have another idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FigureCanvasTkAgg does not have a destroy method. So I tried:

```
for args in lots_of_things_to_make:
    fig = Figure()
    frame = Frame(root)
    do_the_fancy_graphing(fig, *args)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)
    fig.savefig(out_path)
    frame.destroy()
```

but no luck, turns out FigureCanvasTkAgg.__init__ binds to the toplevel it is placed in, so:

```
for args in lots_of_things_to_make:
    fig = Figure()
    top = Toplevel(root)
    do_the_fancy_graphing(fig, *args)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=top)
    fig.savefig(out_path)
    top.destroy()
```

Seems to be working for me.